# Django session timer countdown

Tags: python, session, django, template, contador

Eu tenho isso em minha tela de login: `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1200 # 20 minutos` e gostaria de mostrar o tempo restante em meu template.

Alguém conhece um bom middleware ou pacote para Django que adicione um contador do tempo que falta para acabar a sessão de login. Não achei nada integrado com o Django, apenas soluções em JavaScript.

Comment: A solução é calcular a diferença entre o `datetime` que foi feito o login e esse `datetime` + 20min, pegar o resultado e jogar para o template em forma de segundos. Com o JavaScript que você tem é só colocar a contagem a partir dos segundos restantes.

Comment: Correção: (`datetime` do login + 20min) - `datetime` atual

Comment: Hei Origon, desta forma eu teria que manipular o mesmo dado, os 20 minutos duas vezes, na sessão e na view. Criei uma view para requisição ajax, que me retorna o tempo restante e com um countdown em jquery eu o mostro no template. Dessa forma fica tudo sincronizado. 

key = request.COOKIES['sessionid']
session = Session.objects.get(session_key=key)

tempo_restante = session.expire_date

Formato a data em um Json como eu gostaria e o valido

Comment: Gostaria de saber suas motivações para implementar isso. O problema original tem relação com seus usuários estarem ativamente usando o sistema e perderem o acesso entre requests pela sessão ter expirado? Este é o comportamento padrão do `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`, ele impõe uma data fim mesmo que seu usuário esteja usando ativamente o sistema. Eu costumo implementar um middeware que renova a data de expiração a cada novo acesso, é uma abordagem diferente para tratar o problema. Se isso fizer sentido para você, posso postar um trecho de código deste middleware como resposta. Abs!

Comment: Bom acredito que para ter um contador você vai precisar de jquery, socket.io para fazer o mesmo, caso queira solução python de uma lida em Tornado ou libs para realtime em python.